# How to connect logstash from logstash?

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, logstash, filebeat

I want to use one logstash send data to multiple logstash services.

If I use this setting in k8s, it can work.

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: logstash
  name: logstash
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash
  ports:
    - name: "5044"
      port: 5044
      targetPort: 5044
```

filebeat.yml

```
    filebeat.inputs:
      - type: log
        enabled: true
        paths:
          - /var/log/log1.json
        tags: ["log1"]

    processors:
      - decode_json_fields:
          fields: ["message"]
          process_array: true
          max_depth: 1
          target: ""
          overwrite_keys: true
          add_error_key: false

    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["logstash-log1.default.svc.cluster.local:5044"]
```

logstash.yml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap-logstash
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
    xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
  logstash.conf: |
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }

    filter {
    }

    output {
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
```

But if I change to another way, set output from another logstash instance as:

k8s services:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: logstash-log1
  name: logstash-log1
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash-log1
  ports:
    - name: "5044"
      port: 5044
      targetPort: 5044
```

logstash.yml

```
    output {
      if "log1" in [tags] {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
        tcp {
          mode => "client"
          host => "logstash-log1.default.svc.cluster.local"
          port => 5044
          codec => "json"
        }
      }
    }
```

target logstash's logstash.yml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap-logstash
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
    xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
  logstash.conf: |
    input {
      tcp {
        port => 5044
      }
    }

    filter {
    }

    output {
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
```

The communication can be confimed, it works. But the data seems didn't send to `logstash-log1.default.svc.cluster.local:5044`.

If use curl to test from origin logstash,

```
curl logstash-log1.default.svc.cluster.local:5044
```

Can get log data in the target logstash:

```
{
  "port" => 37424,
  "host" => "10.12.8.213"
}
{
  "port" => 37424,
  "host" => "10.12.8.213"
}
{
  "port" => 37424,
  "host" => "10.12.8.213"
}
{
  "port" => 37424,
  "host" => "10.12.8.213"
}
```

So the problem may be the configuration between 2 logstash. Doesn't tcp input/output methods work?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`lumberjack` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-lumberjack.html) and [`beats` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html).

This is the recommended approach for Logstash-to-Logstash communication, and is explained in detail [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/ls-to-ls.html) in the logstash docs.

Comment: Please do be aware that lumberjack sets up a tcp handshake and it will keep on using that connection until there is a broken pipe, if you want to make sure there is an even load, this is not the way to do it, what you can do is choose any other output that allows for even spread of load.

Answer (score 0):

My solution thus far has been to use gelf between the two logstashes:

logstash-01: taking input from beats and sending it to logstash-02

/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash-01.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    }
}
output {
  gelf {
    id => "%{host}"
    host => "logstash-02.example.com"
    port => 9899
  }
}
```

logstash-02: receiving from logstash-01

/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash-02.conf

```
input {
  gelf {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    use_udp => true
    port => 9899
    strip_leading_underscore => false
    remap => false
  }
}
```

YMMV